# Python extract common patterns of length X among a set of sequences

Tags: python, collections, sequence, counter, python-itertools

Let's say I have the following :
`data = ['ABCD', 'ABABC', 'BCAABCD']`
I'm trying to make a function, that uses [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) taking three argvs, one for the data, second for the minimum proportion of the number of sequences that must have this pattern for being taken into account, and a third one that is the maximum pattern length.

A working function should gives me the following :

```
>>> check(data, 0.50, 2)
Counter({'A': 3, 'AB': 3, 'B': 3, 'BC': 3, 'C': 3, 'CD': 2, 'D': 2})

>>> check(data, 0.34, 4)
Counter({'A': 3, 'AB': 3, 'ABC': 3, 'ABCD': 2, 'B': 3, 'BC': 3, 'BCD': 2, 'C': 3, 'CD': 2, 'D': 2})
```

I'm really lost on this thing, I just know how to get the combinations thing for two or more letter like this :

```py
Counter(combinations(data[0], 2)) & Counter(combinations(data[1], 2)) & Counter(combinations(data[2], 2))
```

And I also know how to get the sum of the letters in all elements of data with :

```py
Counter(data[0]) + Counter(data[1]) + Counter(data[2])
```

(Strange thing, I couldn't manage to do this sum using list comprehension as I would've liked to do because of an error saying I can't do '+' between 'str' and 'int'

If you guys can't give me full code, no problem, I only need some guidance on how to start the whole thing and to get the logic.

Have a nice day to the one who read my whole thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function to get all combinations of the merged substrings (with length `<=` the maximum) in `data` and find the substring intersections using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = ['ABCD', 'ABABC', 'BCAABCD']
def combos(d, l, c = []):
   if c:
      yield ''.join(c)
   if d and len(c) < l:
      yield from combos(d[1:], l, c+[d[0]])
      if not c:
          yield from combos(d[1:], l, c)

def check(d, p, l):
   _d = defaultdict(set)
   for i in d:
      for j in combos(i, l):
         _d[j].add(i)
   return {a:len(b) for a, b in _d.items() if len(b)/len(d) >= p}

print(check(data, 0.50, 2))
print(check(data, 0.34, 4))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 3, 'AB': 3, 'B': 3, 'BC': 3, 'C': 3, 'CD': 2, 'D': 2}
{'A': 3, 'AB': 3, 'ABC': 3, 'ABCD': 2, 'B': 3, 'BC': 3, 'BCD': 2, 'C': 3, 'CD': 2, 'D': 2}
```